# Is it possible to override UITextField enabled/disabled states Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have custom UITextField category for customising UITextField appearance for whole app. But sometimes I need to have disabled statements of field and look grayout also with custom design.

```
 Like to have custom [_myUITextfield setDisabled];
```

and for setDisabled to have

```
 enabled = NO;
 backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
 textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

I tried to add class method but can't access to self.

What I have for now is below, to customise the design:

CutomTextField.h

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField
@end
```

CutomTextField.m

```
@implementation CustomTextField

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        [self.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [self.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0 green:180/255.0 blue:180/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth: 0.0];

        [self.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
        [self.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:122/255.0 green:122/255.0 blue:122/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
        [self.layer setShadowRadius:1.0];
        [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

        UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        self.leftView = paddingView;
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: just customize the same code by adding a if-condition to check whether enbled or disabled.

Comment: thanks for tip, it seems good option!